# How to delete rows with bi-directional dependencies?

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, constraints, delete-row

I'm using Oracle 10g Express and trying to delete records from tables with bi-directional constraints. I'm trying to un-thread hundreds of tables and dependencies generated via Hibernate (which can't be changed at this point), but here is an *extremely* simplified example:

```
create table TableA (id number(19,0) not null, ..., rTableA_id number(19,0), primary key (id));
create table TableB (id number(19,0) not null, ..., rTableB_id number(19,0), primary key (id));

alter table TableA add constraint FKA1 foreign key (rTableA_id) references TableB;
alter table TableB add constraint FKB1 foreign key (rTableB_id) references TableA;
```

Trying to delete entries from either table returns the following:
EDIT: This happens in my case with foreign keys prefixed with **SYS_**

```
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (XXX.FKA1) violated - child record found
```

I've also tried to disable constraints but all attempts are futile:

```
ORA-02297: cannot disable constraint (XXX.FKA1) - dependencies exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to add `INITIALLY DEFERRED` because the databases (as well as the underlying Hibernate scripts) already exist. For new systems, this would have been an option, however, there are many tools (of which I only know several) which rely on the Database in its current form and I was too afraid of any unintended side-effects by adding this parameter to 700 tables.

Therefore, I used the following solution:

```
alter table TableA MODIFY CONSTRAINT FKA1 DISABLE;
alter table TableB MODIFY CONSTRAINT FKB1 DISABLE;

delete from TableA where id = 1;
delete from TableB where id = 2;

alter table TableA MODIFY CONSTRAINT FKA1 ENABLE;
alter table TableB MODIFY CONSTRAINT FKB1 ENABLE;
```

Answer (score 5):

I have to wonder how your data got in this state in the first place, since your foreign keys are `not null`.  If both tables were empty to start with, you'd never be able to insert a row into either table.

Ignoring that for a moment, recreating your scenario, I have no problem disabling the constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE tablea(id NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL, 
                    rtablea_id NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL, 
                    PRIMARY KEY(id))
/

CREATE TABLE tableb(id NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL, 
                    rtableb_id NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL, 
                    PRIMARY KEY(id))
/

INSERT INTO tablea
VALUES     (1, 2)
/

INSERT INTO tableb
VALUES     (2, 1)
/

ALTER TABLE tablea ADD CONSTRAINT fka1 
                       FOREIGN KEY (rtablea_id)  
                       REFERENCES tableb
/
ALTER TABLE tableb ADD CONSTRAINT fkb1  
                       FOREIGN KEY (rtableb_id)  
                       REFERENCES tablea
/
ALTER TABLE tablea MODIFY CONSTRAINT fka1 DISABLE
/
ALTER TABLE tableb MODIFY CONSTRAINT fkb1 DISABLE
/
delete tablea
/
delete tableb
/
commit
/
```

Result:

```
Table created.
Table created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
Table altered.
Table altered.
Table altered.
Table altered.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
Commit complete.
```

I'm not sure how you'd get a `ORA-02297` error when attempting to disable a foreign key.  That error is typically seen when disabling a primary or unique key that a foreign key relies upon.

I suspect what you really want to do is set the constraints to `initially deferred`. This would allow you to perform inserts and deletes to each table individually, as long as the corresponding row was updated or deleted before the transaction is commited:

```
CREATE TABLE tablea(id NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,  
                    rtablea_id NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,  
                    PRIMARY KEY(id))
/

CREATE TABLE tableb(id NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,  
                    rtableb_id NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,  
                    PRIMARY KEY(id))
/

ALTER TABLE tablea ADD CONSTRAINT fka1 
                       FOREIGN KEY (rtablea_id) 
                       REFERENCES tableb 
                       INITIALLY DEFERRED
/
ALTER TABLE tableb ADD CONSTRAINT fkb1 
                       FOREIGN KEY (rtableb_id) 
                       REFERENCES tablea 
                       INITIALLY DEFERRED
/

INSERT INTO tablea
VALUES     (1, 2)
/

INSERT INTO tableb
VALUES     (2, 1)
/

INSERT INTO tableb
VALUES     (3, 1)
/

COMMIT
/

DELETE tableb
WHERE  id = 2
/

UPDATE tablea
SET    rtablea_id   = 3
WHERE  id = 1
/

COMMIT
/
```

Result:

```
Table created.
Table created.
Table altered.
Table altered.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
Commit complete.
1 row deleted.
1 row updated.
Commit complete.
```

Comment: My bad! The foreign keys are not "not null". My best guess is that the ORA-02297 error comes from the nesting of hundreds of tables via foreign keys, of which I am trying to unwind. Actually I'm seeing now that the trouble-making foreign keys begin with SYS_.

Comment: @glenneroo: Constraints that start with `SYS_` are typically primary keys that were not named at the time of creation. I'm unaware of any way to create system-named foreign keys. If they are primary keys, you can add `cascade` to the end of the `disable` command to disable all dependent foreign keys at the same time.

Comment: Adding `cascade` worked but I still can't delete some tables due to `ORA-02292` errors. Looking at `user_constraints` table it seems some constraints are still enabled. That aside, I also can't re-enable the constraints (after deleting rows) due to `ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list`. I wonder if I can just delete and re-create the constraints?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that Hibernate cannot be told to create the constraints as deferrable?  If the DDL doesn't use the `DEFERRABLE` keyword, the constraints will be non-deferrable by default.  That is going to mean that you won't be able to delete the data.  If you have a schema with circular references, you would always want to declare your foreign key constraints to be deferrable.

You could drop the constraints, delete the data, and then re-create the constraints (either using Hibernate's DDL or by adding the `INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE` clause at the end).  But that would be a major pain if you delete data from either table with any sort of frequency.  You'll also tend to have problems inserting new data if the new A row wants to reference the new B row you're creating.

Comment: I could tell Hibernate to, but it's a live system so I'll have to build an update script to alter foreign keys to add the keyword, if that's even possible. I've thought about dropping/re-creating constraints as this is not a time critical operation - it's basically for devs to clean up corrupt data.