# How to delete rows with specific column that hold duplicate values where each has constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

When trying to [delete duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) with:

```
DELETE FROM staff
WHERE staff_id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(staff_id) FROM staff GROUP BY store_id);
```

There is an error:

> [23503] ERROR: update or delete on table "staff" violates foreign key
>   constraint "payment_staff_id_fkey" on table "payment" Detail: Key
>   (staff_id)=(3) is still referenced from table "payment".

Indeed, payment has FK constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE public.payment
(
  payment_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('payment_payment_id_seq'::regclass),
  customer_id integer NOT NULL,
  staff_id smallint NOT NULL,
  rental_id integer NOT NULL,
  amount numeric(5,2) NOT NULL,
  payment_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT payment_pkey PRIMARY KEY (payment_id),
  CONSTRAINT payment_customer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
      REFERENCES public.customer (customer_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT payment_rental_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (rental_id)
      REFERENCES public.rental (rental_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT payment_staff_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (staff_id)
      REFERENCES public.staff (staff_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

It is not possible to set `payment.staff_id = null` because of `NOT NULL` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212664/delete-from-two-tables-with-circular-foreign-keys).

What is the easiest way to solve this?

Comment: `WHERE store_id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(staff_id) FROM staff GROUP BY store_id)` this doesn't look good, you are comparing store_ids to staff_ids.

Comment: Which means you try to delete all staff, except for one staff member per store. Highly improbable this is what you really want.

Comment: It's exactly what I need `delete all staff, except for one staff member per store` since I have @OneToOne mapping in Hibernate that fails otherwise.   Maybe I should modify some constraints to `ON DELETE CASCADE
          DEFERRABLE` .....

Comment: And contrary to the title of your question, it are not duplicates, it are different persons, who happen to work for the same store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a problem of a data model, not a db.

At this moment constraints strictly forbid you to execute such deletion. Looks like there is a strictly rule "*Every payment does have to be linked with a staff member who worked with it and payment info should remain in db*". So, if there is a need in deleteion of staff member record you have to change that rule. Here are some options:

- ***Not*** every payment does have to be linked with a staff member who worked with it and payment info should remain in db. In that case you just have to make staff_id nullable and alter constraint to ON DELETE SET NULL
- *Every payment does have to be linked with a staff member who worked
  with it and payment info **not necessarily** should remain in db*. If you want to delete payments processed by removed staff member, change ON DELETE RESTRICT to ON DELETE CASCADE
- *Every payment does have to be linked with a staff member who worked
  with it **or another one** and payment info should remain in db*. May be it's possible to re-reference payment to another staff member, for example head of organization. In such case you should change constraint to ON DELETE SET DEFAULT (and set a default value ofc).
- One more option is to keep staff member id by marking record in public.staff as archive instead of deleting. If so, you need a way to do so: some bool column in public.staff or something like that.

Anyway it's firstly issue of business logic but not technical issue.

Edit: It's either question has been altered or I missed note "When trying to delete duplicates". If so, you just need to update entities linked with stuff members to de-reference them to actual ones instead of duplicates before deletion.